# ReactJS change PropTypes onHover , is that possible?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-proptypes

is there a way to change PropTypes , lets say a "bool" from false to true onHover from a component?

Comment: Not too clear, can you give us your code

Comment: Yes? You can utilize `onMouseEnter`/`onMouseLeave` (or the pointer versions) to toggle some state value that is passed as prop. If you share a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example we may better assist.

Comment: actualy there is no real code, if you got an Component, you can add with prop-types, any proptypes you want to your component, as string, bool, int etc... , and i just want to change a bool from true to false onHover, but maybe i just figured it out, if so, gonna post the answer ASAP

Comment: If you change a bool from true to false, you are not changing the PropType - it's still a bool. A type change would be from bool to string, for instance, and as far as I know that's not possible inside the render cycle (and defeats the purpose of setting type in the first place).